# javascript setTimeout() outputs save as variables

Tags: javascript

I want to save setTimeout()  outputs as variables.

for example:

```
function time() {
 return  (new Date).getTime();
 }

for (var x=0; x<10; x++) {
   setTimeout( time() , 2000);
}
```

the above javascript code returns  time in milliseconds every 2 seconds upto 10 times.

So we'll get 10 outputs. I want to save those outputs as 10 variables. So i'll be able to calculate  average etc.

Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use an array with the [push method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you describe. But to answer your question, use a single Array instead of 10 variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative loop could be

**EDIT:** based on one of your comments, this script now outputs the average, too

```
var times = [];

var calculateAverage = function() {
  var sum = times.reduce(function(sum, t) { return sum += t; }, 0);
  console.log("Average:", sum/times.length);
};

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  times.push((new Date).getTime());
  if (times.length === 10) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    calculateAverage();
  }
}, 2000);
```

Output

> Average: 1376671898024

Answer (score 9):

> the above javascript code returns time in milliseconds every 2 seconds upto 10 times.

No, it doesn't. It calls `time` **immediately** and passes its return value into `setTimeout` (which won't do anything with it), because you have the `()` after `time`. If you had `setTimeout(time, 2000)`, it would schedule 10 calls to `time`, but **all** of them would occur roughly 2 seconds later (not *every* two seconds).

> So we'll get 10 outputs. I want to save those outputs as 10 variables

This is what arrays are for. :-)

```
var times = [];

function time() {
    times.push((new Date).getTime());
    if (times.length < 10) {
        setTimeout(time, 2000);
    }
}

setTimeout(time, 2000);
```

Or if for some reason you can't modify `time` directly:

```
var times = [];

function time() {
    return (new Date).getTime();
}

function nextTime() {
    times.push(time());
    if (times.length < 10) {
        setTimeout(nextTime, 2000);
    }
}

setTimeout(nextTime, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tested your code on jsfiddle. Its not working. It will be great if you post how to calculate average time as well to confirm working code.

Comment: @Vaibhav: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pBYSm/ (I used 3 instead of 10 because I didn't want to wait 20 seconds).